# Are There Common Values of Standard Deviation for Gaussian Noise of an Image?

Tags: noise, image-processing, gaussian

For example, it occurs to me that there might be a standard deviation value of Gaussian noise in which the human eye could no longer distinguish an object because the standard deviation is very high and many edges were removed because of that amount of noise. Or I think maybe there are values of standard deviation in which the human eye can better distinguish an object in an image because the model of vision of the eye is modeled in such a way that these values of standard deviation allow the eye to recognize or distinguish an object. Is there any research about this that I am commenting on? Are there "important" values of Gaussian noise standard deviation in an image?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily have a look on the values of the STD on [Image Denoising Papers](https://scholar.google.co.il/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=Image%20Denoising):

- The range of 1-15 is considered low.
- The range 15-30 is considered medium.
- The range 30-50 (Even above) is considered high.

The above values is for images in the range `[0, 255]`.